# Reset path variable from jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have the following problem. See code below.

```java
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editUser" commandName="user">
        <div id="editUserDialog" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit user</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form:select id="slc_picker" path="id" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" onchange="javascript:onSelectEditUser()">
                            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="us">
                                <option>${us.id}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:input id="surname" path="surname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname"/>
                        <form:input id="name" path="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                        <form:input id="fatherName" path="fatherName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Father Name"/>
                        <form:input id="mobilePhone" path="mobilePhone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Phone"/>
                        <form:input id="email" path="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save user"/>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetSelectpicker()"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

This is spring form in jsp page. After I clicked submit button, I was sending request to controller, and all my form `input(name, surname,... and other)` were reset, but after I clicked close button, they contain value, and I want reset all form:input, when I clicked close button. I suppose, thet I must reset object `/commandName="user"/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing button type to `reset`

```
 <button type="reset" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I added yours code, I had the same problem.